# How can I get a snapshot of the whole ethereum blockchain?

Tags: snapshot

I'm currently running a geth node (fast mode) on my machine. And I want to know is there any way to get a snapshot of the whole blockchain from geth? Thank you so much if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you mean the world state (i.e. a mapping from accounts to account states) or the blockchain itself (the blockheader, the transactions and so on?)